# Accessing an local ip adres via asp.net

Tags: asp.net, telnet

I am working on a school project, for the project i need to telnet to a server and give a command. (the telnet enviroment is currently working now)

my question is:
if i debug the code it works flawlessly, but when i upload it to a domain server it cant access a local ip address. is it possible to fix this? (that the telnet enviroment is running at the client side, something like that?)

ASP.Net Code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
                    IP adres: <asp:TextBox ID="IP" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        Poort: <asp:TextBox ID="Poort" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Verbinden" runat="server" Text="Verbinden" OnClick="Verbinden_Click" /> <asp:Label ID="Verbindingstatus1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Verbindingverbreken" runat="server" Text="Verbinding Verbreken" OnClick="Verbindingverbreken_Click"/> <br />


        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Lamp1Aan" runat="server" Text="Lamp 1 aan" OnClick="Lamp1Aan_Click"/> <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Lamp1Uit" runat="server" Text="Lamp 1 uit" OnClick="Lamp1Uit_Click"/> <br />
    </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to connect from the server to your own IP? Or what are you meaning with 'local' ip?

Comment: I am trying to connect from the web server (azure) to my local ip (192.168.x.x) is that possible? @kris

Comment: Nope. You would need a static IP